# Cross Platform problem with CSS and overflow

Tags: css, cross-platform, overflow

We have developed a website (only designed for mobile platforms) but we are experiencing a rare failure.

The webis in this URL https://mercadona.mandarinawebs.com

In the website you can find a menu and there is the problem.

This is how it looks in Chrome (Android)
[image: Home with menu in Android]

And this is how it looks in Chrome (iOS)
[image]

As you can see, the menu is not showing in iOS.
All the animation are in webkit.
It doesn't work on iOS for safari or for chrome but it works on Chrome for Android. This is strange becouse I understood that the interpretation of the website was made by the browser not by the OS.

I suspect it has to do with some of this but I am quite lost
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is one class (scroll-in-mobile)

that contains this:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Deleting this the problem is solved and it works for Android or iOS.